# Find conjugacy classes of $G= \left\langle a, b \mid a^4, b^2=a^4, aba=b \right\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be finite group of order $8$ of the form: $G= \left\langle a, b \ \middle|\ a^4, b^2=a^4, aba=b \right\rangle$.

The elements are $\left\lbrace 1, a, a^2, a^3, b, ab, a^2b, a^3b\right\rbrace$.

I want to find the conjugacy classes of $G$.

$\operatorname{Cl}(a)=\left\lbrace b \in G \ \middle|\  \exists g \in G \,\left(b=gag^{-1}\right)\right\rbrace$.

I know that $\operatorname{Cl}(1)=1$ but I really struggle trying to find the others. Can you guide me through the method how to find the non-trivial ones?

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: $\mathcal Cl(1)=1\;$ **always** ...am I missing something?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Then I'll be the \{ \} fairy, letting the OP know that $\{ \}$ is possible to do in math mode. Oh, and `\mid` makes a nicer vertical line for $\{g \mid g \in G\}$. Also `\text{writing}` lets you write text within math mode. All in all, there is a lot you can do to make math look nice if only you know all the little tricks.

Comment: I think you're confusing conjugacy classes for ideals. (At least that's my best guess at where the $Cl(1)=G$ can come from).

Comment: The second relation $b^2=a^4$ is strange, because $a^4=1$. Perhaps you meant to write $b^2=a^2$?

Comment: thanks I edited it,@DerekHolt I double checked and $b^2=a^4$ and its right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a^4=1$, we know $a^3=a^{-1}$. Since $aba=b$, $ab=ba^3$ and $a^3b=ba$. I will make heavy use of this.

Every element in the center of $G$ (e.g., commutes with everything) will have its own conjugacy class. This is because if everything commutes with $a$, then $gag^{-1}=agg^{-1}=a$ for all $g$. It is easy to see that $1$ and $a^2$ both commute with everything.

Next, observe that $bab=bba^3=a^3$, so $a$ and $a^3$ are in the same conjugacy class. Next, $(a)b(a)^{-1}=(a)b(a^3)=a^2b$, so $ab$ and $a^2b$ are in the same conjugacy class. Finally, $(a)ab(a^3)=a^3b$, so $ab$ and $a^3b$ are in the same conjugacy class. So, we have proved that $1$ and $a^2$ are by themselves, $a$ is with $a^3$, $b$ is with $a^2b$, and $ab$ is with $a^3b$. Now show that $a$ cannot be conjugate to $b$ or $ab$, and that $b$ cannot be conjugate to $ab$. Therefore, you have five conjugacy classes, two with one element, and three with two elements.